# ¿Como abro una pagina creada con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox

Estaba escribiendo un plugin para firefox en el cual genero un html con la pagina en la que actua el plugin y quiero mostrar mi html generado en otra pagina nueva, lo que he intentado tiene una forma bastante similar a la siguiente:

```
function crearHTML(){
    return "<html><head></head><body><p>Hola manola</p></body></html>";
}

function abrirPagina(){

    var html = crearHTML();

    var dataURL = "data:text/html;base64," + btoa(html);

    var w = window.open(dataURL);
}
```

En teoria deberia funcionar, pero es como que firefox abre la pestaña y la cierra inemdiatamente, esto no sucede si en lugar de pasar el MIME "text/html" paso "text/plain", en cuyo caso la pagina se mantiene abierta pero obviamente no se renderiza como quiero.
 ¿Alguna idea de por que podria estar sucediento esto?

Comment: Has intentado con: `var w = window.open(dataURL, "_blank");` ??

Comment: Disculpa que me tardara en contestar, he probado con esa alternativa y el resultado es el mismo

Answer (score 1):

La Puedes Abrir Escribiendo-la en la Misma Página Así:

```html
function crearHTML(){
    return "<html><head></head><body><p>Hola manola</p></body></html>";
}

function abrirPagina(){

    var html = crearHTML();

    // var dataURL = "data:text/html;base64," + btoa(html);

    document.write(html);
}
```

Otro Método es Crear un Archivo html en la misma ubicación de la Página, ejemplo:

```html
function crearHTML(){
        return "<html><head></head><body><p>Hola manola</p></body></html>";
    }

    function abrirPagina(){

      var html = crearHTML();

      var txtFile = new File("example.html");
      txtFile.writeln(html);
      txtFile.close();
      window.open("example.html");
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la primera solucion no me es util ya que actua sobre la misma ventana(o pestaña) ya abierta, y necesito una nueva. De todas formas la segunda solucion que propones me resulto interesante, pero a la hora de ejecutarla en la consola para probar recibo el error `TypeError: Not enough arguments to File.` No estoy muy familiarizado con la api de archivos, pero voy a investigar al respecto.